# Including JSP and displaying it in different rows each time

Tags: html, jsp

I am working on an application where in I am required to display the configuration data of the orders in the page.

So, the working model is that when user clicks on a button, an event is fired and a dojo call is invoked which interacts with business layer and gets the config data and loads the response (through js) in innerHtml of one of my jsp page which is included in another jsp page.

Now, i am trying to break the data and display it. The problem here is, that previously I had just one call and one response. Now, there are multiple calls and for each of them I have a response. So, application is working as it is and displaying the configs horizontally. Since, I am including a jsp page, each time request is fired, data gets displayed in the jsp. I want that data should be displayed one after another. That is:

```
First JSP  
Second JSP 
Third JSP 
'n'   JSP
```

But, the jsp's are getting displayed as

> First JSP Second JSP Third JSP 'n'   JSP

Can anyone please help? Any suggestions will be helpful. Thanks

JSP:

```
<tr id='GRP_<c:out value="${id}"/>' <c:out value="${groupStyle}" escapeXml="false"/>>
     <c:if test="${!sdConfigUIGroup.loadOnDemand}">
        <jsp:include page="Service.jsp"/>
      </c:if>
    </tr>
```

JS:

```
function testFunc(arg0, data, response, request) {

if (arguments == null || arguments.length < 4 || !response.responseText || response.responseText == null || !request.content || request.content == null || !request.content.groupUniqueId
        || request.content.groupUniqueId == null) {
    return;
}

var responseHTML = response.responseText;
var id= request.content.id;

var newElement = document.getElementById("GRP_" + id);
innerElement = document.createElement("td");
newElement.appendChild(innerElement);
innerElement.innerHTML = responseHTML;



var afterAddAnotherFunc = 'afterAddAnother_' + groupUniqueId;
if (typeof window[afterAddAnotherFunc] == 'function')
    runFunction(afterAddAnotherFunc, []);

loadAgain(id);
}
```

Comment: Post your code.. It will be more clear

Comment: @Vimal.. code is bit confidential. So, cant post it here. Apologies.. :( But I want to hit the right solution.

Comment: @Vimal... I have added a mock code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function testFunc(arg0, data, response, request) {

if (arguments == null || arguments.length < 4 || !response.responseText || response.responseText == null || !request.content || request.content == null || !request.content.groupUniqueId
        || request.content.groupUniqueId == null) {
    return;
}

var responseHTML = response.responseText;
var groupUniqueId = request.content.groupUniqueId;


var newElement = document.getElementById("GROUP_" + groupUniqueId);

//Creation of table/row/column
//newTable = document.createElement("table");
//newTable.setAttribute("id","DTABLE");
outerElement = document.createElement("tr");
outerElement.setAttribute("id","DROW");
innerElement = document.createElement("td");
innerElement.setAttribute("id","DCOL");

innerElement.innerHTML = responseHTML;
outerElement.appendChild(innerElement);
//newTable.appendChild(outerElement);
newElement.appendChild(outerElement);


var afterAddAnotherFunc = 'afterAddAnother_' + groupUniqueId;
if (typeof window[afterAddAnotherFunc] == 'function')
    runFunction(afterAddAnotherFunc, []);
showOverlay();
msgBox("Page Loading, please wait...");
loadMore(groupUniqueId);
```

}

This is how i have resolved this scenario. Instead of creating td separately, I am creating a row and then appending a column in it. It works for me. Thanks for any suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

Check in the JSP code are not creating all TD elements within the same TR element.

E.g
the next table display data

First JSP Second JSP Third JSP 'n' JSP

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>First JSP</td>
        <td>Second JSP</td>
        <td>Third JSP</td>
        <td>'n' JSP</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And the next table display data.

First JSP
Second JSP
Third JSP
'n'   JSP

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>First JSP</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Second JSP</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Third JSP</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>'n' JSP</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I should you to use a custom Dojo widget for display your data. see a tutorial [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/recipes/custom_widget/).

Comment: I am just including one jsp. The recurrence of calls is making it look it jsp1 jsp2 jsp3. I want to know the mechanism using which i can allign them vertically.

Comment: You can post the HTML table generated for your code.

Comment: I need view the code generated, inspect element on browser and copy it.